# Is this expected behavior for throw in ruby?

Tags: ruby, try-catch, throw

I noticed this behavior while playing with trap and with catch/throw methods to better understand how they can/should be used.

In Ruby the catch and throw methods appear to be intended to be used in pairs:

```
catch(:ctrl_c) do
  trap("SIGINT") { throw :ctrl_c }
  (1.. ).each {|n| print "."; sleep 0.5 }
end

# SIGINT trapped -> throw called -> catch block exits
#   ruby covthrow1p.rb
#   => ........
```

Or with a second parameter provided to the throw method:

```
def stop_script
  puts 'CTRL_C seen'
  exit
end

catch(:ctrl_c) do
  trap("SIGINT") { throw :ctrl_c, stop_script }
  (1.. ).each {|n| print "."; sleep 0.5 }
end

# SIGINT trapped -> throw called -> catch executes stop_script & exits block
#   ruby covthrow2p.rb
#   => ......CTRL_C seen
```

If throw is used alone (naked) with only the key parameter provided, it fails:

```
def stop_script
  puts 'CTRL_C seen'
  exit
end

trap("SIGINT") { throw :ctrl_c }
(1.. ).each {|n| print "."; sleep 0.5 }

# SIGINT trapped -> throw called -> No catch block -> UncaughtThrowError
#   ruby nkdthrow1p.rb
#   => .......nkdthrow1p.rb:8:in `throw': uncaught throw :ctrl_c (UncaughtThrowError)
```

But if a naked throw is used with the second parameter provided, it succeeds!

```
def stop_script
  puts 'CTRL_C seen'
  exit
end

trap("SIGINT") { throw :ctrl_c, stop_script }
(1.. ).each {|n| print "."; sleep 0.5 }


# SIGINT trapped -> throw called -> No catch block -> call stop_script ???
#   ruby nkdthrow2p.rb
#   => ......CTRL_C seen
```

Is this intended behavior? An artifact of implementation? A bug? Seems harmless generally but could cause confusing behavior.

The examples are on Ruby 3.2.2 running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation of the second example is wrong. Let's comment out `exit` for now, so we can see the full execution:

```
def stop_script
  puts 'CTRL_C seen'
  # exit
end

catch(:ctrl_c) do
  trap("SIGINT") { throw :ctrl_c, stop_script }
  (1.. ).each {|n| print "."; sleep 0.5 }
end
```

What actually happens:

- `catch` executes its block
- `trap` sets a `SIGINT` handler
- `each` starts executing, and is interrupted by the keyboard interrupt
- `SIGINT` handler executes
- `throw(:ctrl_c, stop_script)` executes; since `throw` is a method, its arguments need to be evaluated before the method call
- `stop_script` in Ruby is equivalent to `self.stop_script()` if such a method exists, so `stop_script` is executed
- `"CTRL_C seen"` is printed, `puts` returns `nil`
- script would have exit if `exit` wasn't commented out
- as there is no `return`, `stop_script` returns the last statement's value, which is `nil`
- `throw` is finally called as `throw(:ctrl_c, nil)`
- `catch` exits with value `nil`

Your fourth example is equivalent, only missing the first and last step.

Crucially, the second parameter to `throw` is only the value that will be passed to `catch` as its return value. It has no magic "evaluate this later" power: it evaluates before `throw` is called, just like any argument to a method.

If a `throw` is not caught by `catch` by the time the script reaches its natural end, you will get an exception printed. However, in your last example, given that `exit` is executed, the script exits then and there, the exception situation does not occur.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I had not remembered that the method parms have to be evaluated before the method itself is evaluated. Slaps forehead.